# Multi File Selection using using Custom WPF OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, wpf, fileopendialog

I'm using [Custom WPF Dialog box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42008/Extend-OpenFileDialog-and-SaveFileDialog-Using-WPF) to select one or more files.
Problem is that When you select more than a file, it'll throw Argumentexception("Illegal characters in path.") because of

```
void  OnPathChanged(IFileDlgExt sender, string pathName)
```

method on `FileDialogExt` class. Reason for issue is that  pathName for multiple file is like:

```
D:\Development\ "WpfCustomFileDialog.dll"  "WpfCustomFileDialog.pdb"
```

Which is not a valid parameter for

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName
```

and it'll throw Argumentexception("Illegal characters in path.").

How can I fix this it?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like there's anything to fix, really, though it is a lousy return value.  You just need to separate or parse your returned `pathName` and call `GetFileName()` with each actual name.

Assuming your `D:\` line is a string, you should be able to `.Split('"')`.  Iterate through the resulting array to `.Trim()` the errant whitespace and get rid of the now-empty entries (the spaces between quoted names).

If you then combine the first array element (the folder) with each other element (the file), those should be your valid file names.

If you're including the project as source, you might want to do this work inside the window, and return a `List<String>` or something, rather than that ugly string.